# How to centralize a "short bio"?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've made a short bio for me, which has my picture, my name and e-mail. I've been trying for hours to centralize it in my page, but I can't find a way to do it.

I used Bootstrap for this, making a column with size 2 for the picture and a column with size 10 for the text. I tried removing the whole grid thing, working with `float: left` and `float: right` to align the image and text and then centralizing everything, tried `display: block; margin: 0 auto;` too, but no success.

I believe the solution lies in creating a single element which has the image and text side to side and then centralizing it, though I can't seem to find a way to do it.

I would be grateful if someone explained how to achieve the desired effect.

**Edit:** Here's a picture of what I mean to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip15p.png

That's what I got right now:

```css
.profile-pic {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-9">
      <img class="img-responsive profile-pic" src="https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/9438853">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-auto">
      <h1>Telmo "Trooper"</h1>
      <h4><a href="mailto:telmo.trooper@gmail.com">telmo.trooper@gmail.com</a></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What will be the result? Your picture then below it is your name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined a class `mycenter` and set the flexbox property for it. The class is added to the `row`.
Please note the flex property may have compliance issues for older browsers. See [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) for details.

```css
.profile-pic {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.mycenter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row mycenter">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-9">
      <img class="img-responsive profile-pic" src="https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/9438853" width="200">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-auto">
      <h1>Telmo "Trooper"</h1>
      <h4><a href="mailto:telmo.trooper@gmail.com">telmo.trooper@gmail.com</a></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! I'll paste the same thing I commented in the other answer: I think I wasn't clear enough with my question, what I mean to achieve is something like this: https://i.imgur.com/vWgPg2M.png I would like to keep this distance between the text and image (that's what I got right now) and centralize the whole thing on the screen.

Comment: Your code does what I want without Bootstrap, so I ended up removing the grid definitions I had set. It doesn't look quite as good in a phone right now, so I'm gonna figure that out. Your answer solves the problem, though. Much appreciated! (For anyone interested, this is how the code looks right now: https://pastebin.com/b5ThdyLk)

Comment: This solution worked for me, I just removed ```text-align: center; ``` to avoid the text being centralized.

Answer (score 1):

I used the `offset` class of Bootstrap to push the `div`, and added `text-align:center;`

**NOTE:** This is only applicable when the browser's size is within the range of `col-xs`, this is because you included `col-md`, meaning when it reached the range of `col-md`, it will use whatever you put in `col-md`. To make it applicable to all, you can remove `col-md` in both `div` so that the `col-xs` will be the default class for all sizes

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-pic {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
      <img class="img-responsive profile-pic" src="https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/9438853">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
      <h1>Telmo "Trooper"</h1>
      <h4><a href="mailto:telmo.trooper@gmail.com">telmo.trooper@gmail.com</a></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! I think I wasn't clear enough with my question, what I mean to achieve is something like this: https://i.imgur.com/vWgPg2M.png I would like to keep this distance between the text and image (that's what I got right now) and centralize the whole thing on the screen.